# Как сохранить в файл результат работы

Tags: html

Есть картинка, на которую нанесены сверху(через position: absolute) поля, в которые заносятся данные из БД. Как сохранить эту картинку с данными? Когда выводишь на печать все нормально. А как именно сохранить на компьютере клиента эту картинку с данными?

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, как конкретно заносятся данные из базы, какой ЯП Вы используете на серверной части, и множества других факторов. Но вообще, как правило, в таких случаях лучше использовать Canvas, на котором будет размещено изображение и Ваши кастомные поля. Потом этот Canvas в несколько строк на JavaScript'е можно сохранить, как картинку.